# Not entering info on tax return

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, student-loan, interest

My wife and I make too much to get any deduction for our student loan interest. Our situation also puts us in the Standard Deduction, and we arent itemizing. Question is, do I need to enter all our 1098-E info, since it is moot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in like manner to how you aren't required to report your medical expenses to the government- unless you are claiming that deduction, or report your charitable contributions, business expenses, etc.

Reporting requirements focus around things which affect your taxes owed.  Withhold information about your income, on the other hand, and you are liable to get in some hot water.